# Monitor progress when running MySQL queries from command line in Windows using a batch file

Tags: mysql, file, batch-file

I'm running MySQL queries from within Windows command prompt by utilizing a batch file.

The file contains:

```
@echo off
cd "c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin"
echo Please type the root password
set /p password=
mysql -uroot -p%password% < C:\Temp\GenerateDB.sql
echo Please wait while script is executing and when finished successfully
Pause
mysql -uroot -p%password% < C:\Temp\UpgradeSchema.sql
echo Please wait while script is executing and when finished successfully
Pause
Exit
```

My only problem is that I cannot know if the first query (GenerateDB.sql) is complete or not in order to proceed to the next one(UpgradeSchema.sql).

Is there a way to get a prompt when it is complete or even better track real time progress as when you run the script from MySQL Command Client?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I guess it's not possible to see the progress (not sure) but you could try to make your script wait until the first command has finished. Try to use `start /wait mysql -uroot -p%password% < C:\Temp\GenerateDB.sql`

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer! If I add the line with "start", it executes mysql.exe in another separate cmd window but not the GenerateDB.sql.

Comment: `start` is not enough, it has to be `start /wait`. And yes, a new window will pop up but the first one should wait for the new one to terminate before it goes on. If you want to avoid this new windos you can also check the tasklist in a loop and keep looping until the mysql.exe disappears from the list (means your command is done). This would look something like this: `:LOOP <br> FOR /f "tokens=*" %%A IN ('tasklist^ /v^| findstr /i /c:"mysql.exe"') DO GOTO LOOP` ; EDIT: <br> means new line - I cant insert a new line into a comment ;-)

Comment: I have tried it like this but the new window that opens does nothing...     "@echo off
    cd "c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin"
    echo Please type the root password
    set /p password=
    start /wait mysql -uroot -p%password% <        C:\Temp\GenerateDB.sql
    echo Please wait while script is executing and when finished      successfully
    pause"

Comment: @MichaelS Sorry for the above comment's format. It does not allow me to edit it anymore.

Comment: And what about my second idea where you make your script wait until the mysql.exe task disappears from the task list?

Comment: I've tried it as well with the same result. For some reason when you run the mysql command in a DOS prompt you do not get to know what is happening with the script's progress. On the other hand injecting the query to a new MySQL Command Line Client proves a bit difficult. With both way you sent me, the Client launches but nothing runs inside it. It just sits there logged in waiting for a command.